Colormap along the line curve rather than the axes
Using data from a file, I would like to color the line curve using a custom gradient. However, I would like the gradient coloring to span the line curve rather than the axis.
To better illustrate the need, I am trying to obtain something as the following:

The first points are in light shades of gray. The final points are in darker shades of gray, so that one can guess where the curve starts and where the curve ends (or something of the sort).
For example, using the following code, I can color the curve, but then the clear colors are below, and the dark ones above:
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \begin{axis}[     
        colormap={bw}{
            gray(0cm)=(0.9);
            gray(1cm)=(0.1); 
        }
    ]
    \addplot[
        mesh,
%       scatter src = \thisrowno{0}
%       point meta=y,
        samples=50    ]
    table{
        0.7854  0
        0.68339 -0.33082
        0.4331  -0.57931
        0.15246 -0.70337
        -0.1524 -0.71567
        -0.51191    -0.57501
        -0.77863    -0.28131
        -0.81496    0.074278
        -0.62054    0.39929
        -0.32115    0.60124
        -0.084222   0.67267
        0.15632 0.67815
        0.51758 0.54472
        0.81539 0.24132
        0.86077 -0.12911
        0.62647 -0.46473
        0.26019 -0.65677
        -0.022075   -0.68099
        -0.23457    -0.63331
        -0.53077    -0.47912
        -0.77676    -0.18271
    };         
    \end{axis}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

Which produces the following:

What I would like is for the first points to be in light grays and for the last points to be in the darker tones of the gradient.
I tried playing a little with the scatter src and point meta options but I cannot get the desired output.
Can this be achieved with pgfplots?

I am not familiar pgfplot, but i can plot this gradient plot using l3draw. Fisrt, using the data you provided, see:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% data
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;}{
  0.7854,     0;
  0.68339,   -0.33082;
  0.4331,    -0.57931;
  0.15246,   -0.70337;
  -0.1524,   -0.71567;
  -0.51191,  -0.57501;
  -0.77863,  -0.28131;
  -0.81496,   0.074278;
  -0.62054,   0.39929;
  -0.32115,   0.60124;
  -0.084222,  0.67267;
  0.15632,    0.67815;
  0.51758,    0.54472;
  0.81539,    0.24132;
  0.86077,   -0.12911;
  0.62647,   -0.46473;
  0.26019,   -0.65677;
  -0.022075, -0.68099;
  -0.23457,  -0.63331;
  -0.53077,  -0.47912;
  -0.77676,  -0.18271
}


% color gradient
\color_set:nnn {gray}{HTML}{808080}
\cs_set:Npn \color_gradient:n #1 {
  \color_select:n {gray!#1!black}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {Nnx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \draw_path_moveto:n {x}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_gradient:n {x}


\draw_begin:
\draw_cap_round:
% base
\draw_xvec:n {2cm, 0}
\draw_yvec:n {0, 2cm}
% draw
\draw_path_moveto:n {\draw_point_vec:nn {0.785}{0}}
\int_step_inline:nnn {2}{\fp_eval:n {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq-1}}{
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpb_seq {,}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}} 
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpc_seq {,}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\fp_eval:n {#1+1}}} 
  \color_gradient:x {\fp_eval:n {#1*100/\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}}
  \draw_path_moveto:n {
    \draw_point_vec:nn {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
  }
  \draw_path_lineto:n {
    \draw_point_vec:nn {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {1}}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {2}}
  }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw} 
}
\draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}
\draw_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

this is what you want:

I add another example of curve \rho=0.1*\theta, plot data are generated by gnudata, code as below:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{l3draw}


\begin{document}
\ExplSyntaxOn
% data
\seq_set_split:Nnn \l_tmpa_seq {;}{
  0.00000, 0.00000;
  0.03015, 0.00990;
  0.05111, 0.03763;
  0.05522, 0.07755;
  0.03769, 0.12121;
  -0.00252, 0.15865;
  -0.06227, 0.17993;
  -0.13453, 0.17676;
  -0.20910, 0.14396;
  -0.27403, 0.08046;
  -0.31717, -0.01007;
  -0.32801, -0.11939;
  -0.29933, -0.23539;
  -0.22851, -0.34346;
  -0.11839, -0.42820;
  0.02265, -0.47546;
  0.18120, -0.47430;
  0.34016, -0.41870;
  0.48052, -0.30881;
  0.58361, -0.15143;
  0.63339, 0.04025;
  0.61866, 0.24768;
  0.53480, 0.44875;
  0.38480, 0.62018;
  0.17955, 0.74013;
  -0.06287, 0.79084;
  -0.31876, 0.76100;
  -0.56108, 0.64752;
  -0.76235, 0.45642;
  -0.89765, 0.20274;
  -0.94769, -0.09049;
  -0.90120, -0.39441;
  -0.75679, -0.67708;
  -0.52360, -0.90690;
  -0.22097, -1.05606;
  0.12310, -1.10382;
  0.47457, -1.03916;
  0.79666, -0.86251;
  1.05374, -0.58629;
  1.21523, -0.23422;
  1.25912, 0.16069;
  1.17476, 0.55919;
  0.96459, 0.91974;
  0.64443, 1.20277;
  0.24246, 1.37505;
  -0.20323, 1.41346;
  -0.64822, 1.30791;
  -1.04622, 1.06296;
  -1.35387, 0.69797;
  -1.53540, 0.24568;
  -1.56673, -0.25069;
  -1.43849, -0.74159;
  -1.15752, -1.17604;
  -0.74686, -1.50694;
  -0.24387, -1.69615;
  0.30307, -1.71881;
  0.83926, -1.56640;
  1.30909, -1.24821;
  1.66186, -0.79105;
  1.85720, -0.23701;
  1.86959, 0.36033;
  1.69154, 0.94115;
  1.33494, 1.44528;
  0.83050, 1.81853;
  0.22510, 2.01841;
  -0.42245, 2.01894;
  -1.04720, 1.81380;
  -1.58453, 1.41764;
  -1.97684, 0.86515;
  -2.17968, 0.20813;
  -2.16675, -0.48938;
  -1.93309, -1.15735;
  -1.49622, -1.72673;
  -0.89498, -2.13666;
  -0.18610, -2.34088;
  0.56110, -2.31291;
  1.27152, -2.04931;
  1.87180, -1.57063;
  2.29789, -0.91994;
  2.50188, -0.15900;
  2.45729, 0.63758;
  2.16235, 1.38966;
  1.64078, 2.01963;
  0.93999, 2.46042;
  0.12683, 2.66257;
  -0.71877, 2.59980;
  -1.51168, 2.27213;
  -2.17013, 1.70661;
  -2.62412, 0.95510;
  -2.82284, 0.08961;
  -2.74031, -0.80463;
  -2.37855, -1.63751;
  -1.76805, -2.32319;
  -0.96524, -2.78888;
  -0.04733, -2.98255;
  0.89511, -2.87871;
  1.76708, -2.48152;
  2.47872, -1.82505;
  2.95459, -0.97038;
  3.14159, -0.00000
}


% color gradient
\cs_set:Npn \color_gradient:n #1 {
  \color_select:n {blue!#1!green}
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \seq_set_split:Nnn {Nnx}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \draw_path_moveto:n {x}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \color_gradient:n {x}


\draw_begin:
\draw_cap_round:
% base
\draw_xvec:n {2cm, 0}
\draw_yvec:n {0, 2cm}
% draw
\draw_path_moveto:n {\draw_point_vec:nn {0.785}{0}}
\int_step_inline:nnn {2}{\fp_eval:n {\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq-1}}{
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpb_seq {,}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {#1}} 
  \seq_set_split:Nnx \l_tmpc_seq {,}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpa_seq {\fp_eval:n {#1+1}}} 
  \color_gradient:x {\fp_eval:n {#1*100/\seq_count:N \l_tmpa_seq}}
  \draw_path_moveto:n {
    \draw_point_vec:nn {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {1}}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpb_seq {2}}
  }
  \draw_path_lineto:n {
    \draw_point_vec:nn {\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {1}}{\seq_item:Nn \l_tmpc_seq {2}}
  }
  \draw_path_use_clear:n {draw} 
}
\draw_path_use_clear:n {draw}
\draw_end:
\ExplSyntaxOff

\end{document}

this will give the output:



plot data can be read from external file using command like \ior_str_map_inline:Nn, see interface3.pdf for more info.
Maybe you can use some internal pgf macro the plot this type of graph



Your answer does great with the curve coloring, however, I really need my plots to be homogeneous. Any idea about how to put this in a plot from pgfplots ?

@Meclassic Maybe you can look draw multicolor curve with smooth gradient or How to draw an arrow with two colors for more infomation.
